# C# UWP Cards Widget?

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-core, uwp

I saw a simple widget card (IDK what it's named) from Windows Security / Defender. Is it available in UWP Native Widgets or should I implement this on my own?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a card, just a GridViewItem with a [Reveal Highlight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal) style. If you want cards like in Material Design (with shadows) tho, you can try using a [DropShadowPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/dropshadowpanel) from the [Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/).